# How to use spring transaction support with Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I am trying to use spring batch to read file from a .dat file and persist the data into database. My requirement says to either insert all of the data or insert none of the data into table i.e, atomicity. However, using spring batch i'm not able to achieve the same it is reading data in chunks and is inserting data as long as the records are fine. if at some point the record is inappropriate and some db exception is thrown then i want complete rollback which is not happening. Let's say we get error at 2051th record then my code saves 2050 records but i want complete rollback and if all data is good then all N records should be persisted. Thanks in advance for any help or relevant approach that may solve my issue...

NOTE: I have already used Spring Transactional annotation on caller method but it's not working and i'm reading data in a chunk size of 10 items.

MyConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration 
{

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyCompletionListener")
    JobCompletionNotificationListener jobCompletionNotificationListener;

    @StepScope
    @Bean(name="MyReader")
    public FlatFileItemReader<InputMapperDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) throws IOException 
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<InputMapperDTO> newBean = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        newBean.setName("MyReader");
        newBean.setResource(new InputStreamResource(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(fileName))));
        newBean.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        newBean.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return newBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="MyLineMapper")
    public DefaultLineMapper<InputMapperDTO> lineMapper() 
    {
        DefaultLineMapper<InputMapperDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer());
        Reader reader = new Reader();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(reader);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean(name="MyTokenizer")
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer() 
    {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        tokenizer.setNames("InvestmentAccountUniqueIdentifier", "BaseCurrencyUniqueIdentifier",
                "OperatingCurrencyUniqueIdentifier", "PricingHierarchyUniqueIdentifier", "InvestmentAccountNumber",
                "DummyAccountIndicator", "InvestmentAdvisorCompanyNumberLegacy","HighNetWorthAccountTypeCode");
        tokenizer.setIncludedFields(0, 5, 7, 13, 29, 40, 49,75);
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Bean(name="MyBatchProcessor")
    public ItemProcessor<InputMapperDTO, FinalDTO> processor() 
    {
        return new Processor();
    }

    @Bean(name="MyWriter")
    public ItemWriter<FinalDTO> writer() 
    {
        return new Writer();
    }

    @Bean(name="MyStep")
    public Step step1() throws IOException 
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MyStep")
                .<InputMapperDTO, FinalDTO>chunk(10)
                .reader(this.reader(null))
                .processor(this.processor())
                .writer(this.writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name=MyJob")
    public Job importUserJob(@Autowired @Qualifier("MyStep") Step step1) 
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("MyJob"+new Date())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobCompletionNotificationListener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Writer.java

```
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<FinalDTO>
{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends FinalDTO> listOfObjects) throws Exception 
    {
        someRepository.saveAll(listOfObjects);      
    }

}
```

JobCompletionNotificationListener.java

```
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport
{

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) 
    {
        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) 
        {
            System.err.println("****************************************");
            System.err.println("*****    Batch Job Completed      ******");
            System.err.println("****************************************");
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("****************************************");
            System.err.println("*****    Batch Job Failed      ******");
            System.err.println("****************************************");
        }
    }

}
```

MyCallerMethod

```
    @Transactional
    public String processFile(String datFile) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException 
    {
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();

        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        builder.addString("fileName",datFile);
        builder.addDate("date", new Date());
        jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());

        System.err.println("****************************************");
        System.err.println("*****    Total time consumed = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-st)+"      ******");
        System.err.println("****************************************");
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303155/how-does-spring-batch-transaction-management-work

Comment: Thanks a lot, gave me some basic idea to debug with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation I have tried is not provided in batch. For my requirement, I have implemented custom delete which flushes the database upon failure in any step.